# instantsearch menuselect widget is not working sometimes on IE

Tags: javascript, html, algolia, instantsearch.js

Now I'm developing search page by using algolia widgets.
If I don't use menuselect widget, my web page is running well in IE.
But If I use menuselect widget, algolia widgets following menuselect are not displayed.
So I have tried to test only menuselect widget.
Following code shows my test file.

```js
var searchDiscover = instantsearch({
  indexName: 'demo_ecommerce',
  searchClient: algoliasearch('B1G2GM9NG0', 'aadef574be1f9252bb48d4ea09b5cfe5'),
  routing: false,
});


var widget = instantsearch.widgets.menuSelect({
  container: '#brand-list',
  attribute: 'brand',
});
searchDiscover.addWidget(widget);
searchDiscover.start();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.css@7/themes/algolia-min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/app.css" />

    <title>ais-ecommerce-demo-app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ais-InstantSearch">
      <h1>InstantSearch.js e-commerce demo</h1>

      <div class="left-panel">
        <div id="clear-refinements"></div>

        <h2>Brands</h2>
        <div id="brand-list"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-panel">
        <div id="searchbox" class="ais-SearchBox"></div>
        <div id="hits"></div>
        <div id="pagination"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/algoliasearch@3.32.0/dist/algoliasearchLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@3.0.0"></script>
    <script src="./src/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is working on Chrome, but not working on IE.(I can't see menuselect on IE).
In other hand, I can see menuselect live example in following url, but not find code.
https://instantsearchjs.netlify.com/stories/?selectedKind=MenuSelect&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved this issue.
For the widget to work in IE, I can add polyfills to the page:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default,Array.prototype.find,Array.prototype.includes"></script>
```